# All git commands throw unable to find valid certification path to requested target error

Tags: git

I have an Ubuntu VM and all has been well with the `git` installation until very recently, when suddenly today if I execute any `git` command I now see this:

```
$ git pull
Fatal: java.lang.Error encountered.  Details:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
fatal: credential helper '!/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openjdk/1.8.0-181/jre/bin/java -Ddebug=false -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -jar /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.4/libexec/git-credential-manager-2.0.4.jar' told us to quit
```

I found [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47316409/71376) which talks about this issue in Jenkins and references the path `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` but my Ubuntu machine does not have that path and is not using Jenkins.

I'm guessing here that I need to get my corporation's cert installed, but I don't know where to install it.